# Applying a class without ng-class?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to apply a conditional class to many elements in a page (a form with validation, that is) and I would like to apply one of five possible class to each form inputs. Of course I could do something like this for every `input` element...

```
<input class="form-control" ng-model="form.input1" type="text" placeholder="Something here" ng-class="{class1: appliedClass('input1') == 1, class2: appliedClass('input1') == 2, class3: appliedClass('input1') == 3, class4: appliedClass('input1') == 4, class5: appliedClass('input1') == 5}" />
```

But doing this to every `input` element is a little ugly, and if I want to add a sixth possible class, I must add it manually to every `input`.

So I was wondering is there's a way to apply a class provided by a controller function, who would return the class name?

I found [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/cf17c6af475eace31cf52944afd8e10d3afcf6c0), but it's over a year old and it doesn't seem to work with the version I'm using. I tried `ng-attr-class='controller_function_who_returns_a_class_name()'` and it doesn't even evaluate the function.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-class` can still do what you require.

Something like this:

```
ng-class="controller_function_who_returns_a_class_name()"
```

e.g.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-class="getClasses()">
```

**Javascript**

```
$scope.getClasses = function(input) {
  // evaluate input parameter against your conditions
  // then return the string of classes you wanted.
  return 'class1 class2 class3 class4';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! Check this out - it involved creating a controller function itself but you can use the object property to assign the class as follows:

```
$scope.getClassForInput = function () {
    //Function body that returns the class name
};
```

and in your view you can then use it as:

```
<input type="text" ng-class="{'true': getClassForInput()}['true']">
```

Note how you use the index 'true' to get the class assigned to the "true" property.
`ng-class` either expects an expression or you can pass the class name directly too as in in this case

EDIT: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FseG9/) that demonstrates the same

Comment: `ng-class="getClassForInput(1)"` seems to work just fine? I haven't used Angular in a couple months, so not sure if there's a reason for the way you've used it.

Comment: What is this `['true']`, what does it do?

Comment: @godfrzero You mean in my fiddle? It's just passing an argument to the controller function so that the controller function can conditionally pass back the class name

Comment: @JayShukla `ng-class` either expects an object or a class name. In this case, I use an object and then immediately refer to the property `true` of the same object - which basically calls the controller function that passes the class name and it is this class name that is then assigned to `ng-class`

Comment: @callmekatootie I just meant that `ng-class="getClassForInput(1)"` seems to do the job without the complicated object & immediate access using `[true]`.

Comment: @godfrzero oh yeah.. You are right. I have no idea why I made it so complicated. I'll keep it because I posted it first and there is already answer after me that has corrected it